# “As soon as I earn money, I will get a car”

Tags: perfect-constructions

I have a friend learning English: He said he would usually use, “ As soon as I earn money, I will get a car.”. Yet, someone told him to use, “As soon as I have earnt money, I will get a car.”.

I tried to explain it to him. But which would you use, and why? Which looks better, if either matters?

Comment: Do you mean to say "earn money"? Or do you mean to say "earn _**enough**_ money"? Saying "earn money" seems odd to me.

Comment: I just wrote it how they wrote it to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While “earnt” is allowed, “earned” is much more common. [More detail here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/is-earnt-a-real-word)

I would also add “enough”:

- As soon as I earn *enough* money, I will get a car.
- As soon as I have earned *enough* money, I will get a car.

While I have a slight preference for the latter, either is fine; they mean exactly the same thing to me.